# how to extract xml tag values from email body?

Tags: perl

I know the process to extract the body from the email using MIME::PARSER, but in my mail i have xml data. whats is the process to extract xml tag values from the email body?

```
Body:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TEST>

    <test>test</test>
    <test1>test1</test1>
</TEST>
```

Comment: That isn't XML. There is no root element, so it is not well formed.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be called MIME::Parser (https://metacpan.org/module/MIME::Parser) - Perl is a case sensitive language :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the body actually consists of XML, just feed it into your XML parser of choice ([XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig) seems popular these days or you could look at Task::Kensho's [recommended XML modules](https://metacpan.org/module/Task::Kensho#XML-Development:-Task::Kensho::XML)) and use it as normal.